# Chat username highlighter is too eager

Tags: bug, chat, onebox, highlighting

When a post link is shared in chat, e.g. [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8662323), it expands into a 'onebox'. It seems the script that highlights your username (when a user replies to your chat message or 'pings' you with e.g. `@Glorfindel`, see the first message) is a bit too eager; it highlights the occurrence in the onebox as well:

[image]

In this case, it's the same Glorfindel; however, that might be different if external sources (e.g. Wikipedia articles, tweets) are oneboxed.